# GIS Least Cost Spanning Tree in R

Tags: r, spatial-statistics, cost-path

Is there an R package/function that computes a least cost spanning tree given a shapefile or vector containing the latitude/longitude of each point and a raster file that contains the cost of traversing each pixel?

So, I want to be able to type:

`leastcostspanningtree(shapefile, rasterfile)`

and have a shapefile returned with the spanning tree.

I know I could use multiple packages/functions to do this, but I want a clean, simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that is a fairly specific demand and you will most certainly have to write your own function. If this exact function did exists, somebody would have had to code the "clean, simple solution" using multiple functions and packages. What have your tried and did you come up with anything in doing research into the topic?

The closest thing that I can think of is the "minimum.spanning.tree" function in the iGraph library but, the assumption is that you are staring with a graph object and associated node weights. For graphs with node weights, the Prim's algorithm is used to solve the graph. This would be fairly straightforward to construct using spdep, sp and then coercing to an iGraph object.

If you want to step into variants of raster-based least cost analysis in R there are the gdistance and ResistanceGA libraries. Since graph structures are usually a matrix or sparse matrix, it seems like one could adapt code from these least cost packages to run on a graph.